# AVPlayer does not notify about errors

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayer

I need to implement error handling for `AVPlayer`. I create an instance using `AVPlayer(url: audioUrl)` where `audioUrl` is an URL to a remote mp3 file.

I subscribe for notifications like this:

```swift
func observeAudioTrack() {
    guard let currentItem = player.currentItem else { return }

    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerDidFail), name: .AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTime, object: currentItem)
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerDidLogError), name: .AVPlayerItemNewErrorLogEntry, object: currentItem)
}
```

However, none of these methods is called when I test turning off the internet connection or using an invalid URL.

`player.status` is `readyToPlay`, `player.error` is `nil`.

I managed to receive `AVPlayerItemNewErrorLogEntry`, but only for a stream (`m3u8` format).

PS. I'm using iPhone 12 Pro with iOS 15.0 for testing.

Answer (score 0):

*NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemNewErrorLogEntry* is depreciated from iOS 6.0. Use *AVPlayerItem.newErrorLogEntryNotification* instead. It works for me.  The same thing probably applies for *NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime* but I haven't tested it. Use *AVPlayerItem.failedToPlayToEndTimeNotification* instead.

The code for only-code-readers:

```
func observeAudioTrack() {
    guard let currentItem = player.currentItem else { return }

    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerDidFail), name: AVPlayerItem.failedToPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: currentItem)
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerDidLogError), name: AVPlayerItem.newErrorLogEntryNotification, object: currentItem)
}
```

I've found the info in AVFoundation:

```
@available(macOS, introduced: 10.7, deprecated: 100000, message: "Use AVPlayerItem.failedToPlayToEndTimeNotification instead.")
@available(iOS, introduced: 4.3, deprecated: 100000, message: "Use AVPlayerItem.failedToPlayToEndTimeNotification instead.")
@available(tvOS, introduced: 9.0, deprecated: 100000, message: "Use AVPlayerItem.failedToPlayToEndTimeNotification instead.")
@available(watchOS, introduced: 1.0, deprecated: 100000, message: "Use AVPlayerItem.failedToPlayToEndTimeNotification instead.")
public static var AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTime: NSNotification.Name { get }
```

and

```
@available(macOS, introduced: 10.9, deprecated: 100000, message: "Use AVPlayerItem.newErrorLogEntryNotification instead.")
@available(iOS, introduced: 6.0, deprecated: 100000, message: "Use AVPlayerItem.newErrorLogEntryNotification instead.")
@available(tvOS, introduced: 9.0, deprecated: 100000, message: "Use AVPlayerItem.newErrorLogEntryNotification instead.")
@available(watchOS, introduced: 1.0, deprecated: 100000, message: "Use AVPlayerItem.newErrorLogEntryNotification instead.")
public static var AVPlayerItemNewErrorLogEntry: NSNotification.Name { get }
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to register like this
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(finishedPlaying),
name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: playerItem)

Comment: This notifies when the audio successfully played to the end, not about errors.